# Finding the limit of a linear combination of sequences of functions

Tags: limits, dirac-delta, sequence-of-function

I have a rather specific question. I constructed a sequence of functions, that is smooth, which I wanted to converge to the characteristic function for $n\to\infty$:
$$f^q_n(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{n[(x-(q-\frac{\varepsilon}{2})(x-(q+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}))]}} $$
In this sequence of functions $q$ is a certain point on the real axis and $\varepsilon>0$. For $q'=q+\varepsilon$ I want to find the limit of
$$ \frac{d}{dx}[f^{q'}_n(x)]f^q_n(x)- f^{q'}_n(x)\frac{d}{dx}f^q_n(x)$$
for $n\to\infty$.
I tried to sketch it, to get an idea how it might look like:

[image]

Because of this I suppose that for $n\to\infty$ it holds that
$$ \frac{d}{dx}[f^{q'}_n(x)]f^q_n(x)- f^{q'}_n(x)\frac{d}{dx}f^q_n(x)\to \delta_{q+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}(x)$$

Do you have any idea how to verify this idea?
Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Is it $$\frac{d}{dx}\Big[f^{q'}_n(x)f^q_n(x)\Big]$$ or something else ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici its $\frac{d}{dx}[f_n^{q'}(x)]f_n^q(x)$. Meaning, its only the derivative of $f_n^{q'}(x)$.

Comment: I suggest that you fix it in the post to avoid this possible ambiguity

Comment: Did it, thanks!